# Java Reversi Implementation (javafx)

Tags: java, javafx

This is a working Reversi game in JavaFX. The user is 'black' and the computer that plays against the user is 'white'. I tried to structure the code to be object oriented, but I am not sure if I am using object oriented principles correctly. I think I may have stolen the idea to call the player pieces 'owners' from an article somewhere, but all the code here is my own. Please let me know if you have any questions and I will get back to you as soon as I can.

This is the same project as my last question, but now I am asking for code review instead of help debugging.

```
// imports {{{
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import java.lang.Thread;
//}}}
public class Othello extends Application { // {{{
    static final String BOARD_GAME_NAME = "Othello";
    static final int BOARD_SIZE = 10;
    static final int BOX_SIZE = 40;
    static final int FLIP_DURATION = 500;

    static int blackOwnerPoints = 0;
    static int whiteOwnerPoints = 0;

    static final OwnerType startingOwner = OwnerType.BLACK;

    static OwnerType currentTurn = startingOwner;

    static FlowPane root;
    static OthelloPane othelloPane;
    static TitleLabel ownerTurnLabel;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        root = new FlowPane(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        ownerTurnLabel = new TitleLabel(0, true);
        othelloPane = new OthelloPane(BOARD_SIZE, BOX_SIZE, FLIP_DURATION);

        root.getChildren().addAll(ownerTurnLabel, othelloPane);

        updateOwnerTurnTitle();
        setupClickListeners();
        //othelloPane.highlightValidPositions(currentTurn);
        presentStage(stage);

    }

    public void setupClickListeners() { // {{{
        for (int row = 0; row < BOARD_SIZE; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < BOARD_SIZE; column++) {
                final Owner currentOwner = othelloPane.getOwner(row, column);

                final int f_row = row;
                final int f_column = column;

                othelloPane.getBox(row, column).setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
                    if (currentOwner.getType() == OwnerType.NONE && othelloPane.isValidPosition(f_row, f_column, currentTurn)) {

                        currentOwner.setType(currentTurn);
                        othelloPane.updateBoardForFlips(f_row, f_column);

                        blackOwnerPoints = 0;
                        whiteOwnerPoints = 0;

                        for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; j++) {
                                Owner t_owner = othelloPane.getOwner(i, j);
                                if (t_owner.getType() == OwnerType.BLACK) {
                                    blackOwnerPoints++;
                                } else if (t_owner.getType() == OwnerType.WHITE) {
                                    whiteOwnerPoints++;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        nextTurn();

                        if (othelloPane.hasGameEnded()) {
                            String winner = "";
                            boolean haveTied = false;

                            if (whiteOwnerPoints < blackOwnerPoints) {
                                winner = OwnerType.BLACK.toString();
                            } else if (whiteOwnerPoints > blackOwnerPoints) {
                                winner = OwnerType.WHITE.toString();
                            } else {
                                haveTied = true;
                            }

                            ownerTurnLabel.setText(haveTied ? "Tie" : winner + " Wins");
                        } else {
                            //othelloPane.highlightValidPositions(currentTurn);
                            updateOwnerTurnTitle();
                            if (currentTurn == OwnerType.WHITE) {

                                Timeline timeLine = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(FLIP_DURATION), ev -> {
                                    int positionRow = 0;
                                    int positionCol = 0;
                                    int count = 0;
                                    for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++) {
                                        for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE; j++) {
                                            if (othelloPane.isValidPosition(i, j, OwnerType.WHITE)) {
                                                int tempCount = othelloPane.numFlips(i, j);
                                                if (tempCount > count) {
                                                    count = tempCount;
                                                    positionRow = i;
                                                    positionCol = j;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                    Robot.click(othelloPane.getBox(positionRow, positionCol));
                                }));
                                timeLine.play();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    } //}}}
    public void nextTurn() { //{{{
        currentTurn = (currentTurn == OwnerType.BLACK) ? OwnerType.WHITE : OwnerType.BLACK;
    } //}}}
    public void updateOwnerTurnTitle() { // {{{
        ownerTurnLabel.setText(currentTurn + " Player's Turn");
    } //}}}
    public void presentStage(Stage stage) { // {{{
        stage.setTitle(BOARD_GAME_NAME);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    } // }}}
    public static void main(String[] args) { // {{{
        launch(args);
    } //}}}
} //}}}
class Robot { // {{{
    public static void click(Node node) {
        Event.fireEvent(node, new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, node.getLayoutX()/2, node.getLayoutY()/2, node.getLayoutX()/2, node.getLayoutY()/2, MouseButton.PRIMARY, 1, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, null));
    }
} //}}}
class OthelloPane extends GridPane { //{{{
    private String backgroundInHex = "#654321";
    private int boardSize;
    private int boxSize;
    private Duration flipDuration;
    private int[][] directions = {{-1, -1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}};

    private Owner[][] owners;
    private Pane[][] boxes;

    public OthelloPane(int boardSize, int boxSize, double flipDuration) {
        super();

        owners = new Owner[boardSize][boardSize];
        boxes = new Pane[boardSize][boardSize];

        this.boardSize = boardSize;
        this.boxSize = boxSize;
        this.flipDuration = Duration.millis(flipDuration);

        // setup grid constaints
        for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++)
            getRowConstraints().add( new RowConstraints(boxSize));
        for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++)
            getColumnConstraints().add( new ColumnConstraints(boxSize));

        for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < boardSize; j++) {
                Pane box = new Pane();
                Owner owner = new Owner(boxSize, OwnerType.NONE);
                box.setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + backgroundInHex + ";");
                box.getChildren().add(owner);
                setOwner(i, j, owner);
                setBox(i, j, box);
                add(box, j, i);
            }
        }

        int middle = boardSize/2;

        Owner topLeft = getOwner(middle - 1, middle - 1);
        Owner topRight = getOwner(middle - 1, middle);
        Owner bottomLeft = getOwner(middle, middle - 1);
        Owner bottomRight = getOwner(middle, middle);

        topLeft.setType(OwnerType.BLACK);
        bottomRight.setType(OwnerType.BLACK);
        topRight.setType(OwnerType.WHITE);
        bottomLeft.setType(OwnerType.WHITE);

        setGridLinesVisible(true);
        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    }

    public boolean hasGameEnded() {
        boolean containsBlankBox = false;

        for (Owner[] row: owners) {
            for (Owner owner: row) {
                if (owner.getType() == OwnerType.NONE)
                    containsBlankBox = true;
            }
        }

        return !containsBlankBox;
    }

    // flip related
    public void updateBoardForFlips(int originalRow, int originalColumn) {
        OwnerType[][] ownerTypes = new OwnerType[boardSize][boardSize];

        // Setup OwnerType board representation of owners.
        for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < boardSize; j++)
                ownerTypes[i][j] = getOwner(i, j).getType();

        for (int[] directionGroup: directions) {
            int rowDirection = directionGroup[0];
            int columnDirection = directionGroup[1];
            if (isFlipableDirection(originalRow, originalColumn, rowDirection, columnDirection, null)) {
                flipInDirection(ownerTypes, originalRow, originalColumn, rowDirection, columnDirection);
            }
        }

    }

    public boolean isValidPosition(int row, int column, OwnerType type) {
        boolean valid = false;
        Owner owner = getOwner(row, column);
        for (int[] directionGroup: directions) {

                int rowDirection = directionGroup[0];
                int columnDirection = directionGroup[1];
                if (owner.getType() == OwnerType.NONE && isFlipableDirection(row, column, rowDirection, columnDirection, type)) {
                    return true;
                }
        }

        return valid;
    }

    public int numFlips(int originalRow, int originalColumn) {
        OwnerType originalOwnerType = getOwner(originalRow, originalColumn).getType();

        int highCount = 0;

        for (int[] directionGroup: directions) {
            int rowDirection = directionGroup[0];
            int columnDirection = directionGroup[1];

            int count = 0;

            int row = originalRow + rowDirection;
            int column = originalColumn + columnDirection;

            while (row < boardSize && row >= 0 && column < boardSize && column >= 0) {
                OwnerType ownerType = getOwner(row, column).getType();

                if (ownerType == OwnerType.NONE || ownerType == originalOwnerType) {
                    break;
                }

                count++;

                row += rowDirection;
                column += columnDirection;
            }

            if (count > highCount) {
                highCount = count;
            }
        }

        return highCount;
    }

    public void flipInDirection(OwnerType[][] ownerTypes, int originalRow, int originalColumn, int rowDirection, int columnDirection) {
        // Contract: Will not modify the contents of 'ownerTypes', because
        // all flips will act upon the 'owners' array.
        OwnerType originalOwnerType = ownerTypes[originalRow][originalColumn];

        int row = originalRow + rowDirection;
        int column = originalColumn + columnDirection;

        while (row < boardSize && row >= 0 && column < boardSize && column >= 0) {
            OwnerType ownerType = ownerTypes[row][column];

            if (ownerType == OwnerType.NONE || ownerType == originalOwnerType) {
                break;
            }

            Owner owner = getOwner(row, column);

            RotateTransition firstRotator = new RotateTransition(flipDuration, owner);
            firstRotator.setAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
            firstRotator.setFromAngle(0);
            firstRotator.setToAngle(90);
            firstRotator.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
            firstRotator.setOnFinished(e -> owner.setType(originalOwnerType));

            RotateTransition secondRotator = new RotateTransition(flipDuration, owner);
            secondRotator.setAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);
            secondRotator.setFromAngle(90);
            secondRotator.setToAngle(180);
            secondRotator.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);

            new SequentialTransition(firstRotator, secondRotator).play();

            row += rowDirection;
            column += columnDirection;
        }
    }

    public void highlightValidPositions(OwnerType type) {
        for (int i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < boardSize; j++) {
                Owner owner = getOwner(i, j);

                owner.setType(owner.getType());
                owner.setRadius(boxSize/2 -5);
                owner.setOpacity(1);

                for (int[] directionGroup: directions) {
                    int rowDirection = directionGroup[0];
                    int columnDirection = directionGroup[1];

                    if (owner.getType() == OwnerType.NONE && isFlipableDirection(i, j, rowDirection, columnDirection, type)) {
                        owner.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
                        owner.setRadius(boxSize/2 -10);
                        owner.setOpacity(0.2);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isFlipableDirection(int originalRow, int originalColumn, int rowDirection, int columnDirection, OwnerType optionalOwnerType) {
        // hacky way to do an optional parameter
        OwnerType originalOwnerType = (optionalOwnerType == null) ? getOwner(originalRow, originalColumn).getType() : optionalOwnerType;

        int row = originalRow + rowDirection;
        int column = originalColumn + columnDirection;

        int count = 0;
        while (row < boardSize && row >= 0 && column < boardSize && column >= 0) {
            Owner owner = getOwner(row, column);
            OwnerType ownerType = owner.getType();

            if (ownerType == OwnerType.NONE || owner.getFill() == Color.YELLOW) {
                break;
            } else if (ownerType == originalOwnerType) {
                return count > 0;
            }

            row += rowDirection;
            column += columnDirection;
            count++;
        }

        return false;
    }

    // getters
    public Pane getBox(int row, int column) {
        return boxes[row][column];
    }
    public Owner getOwner(int row, int column) {
        return owners[row][column];
    }

    // setters
    private void setBox(int row, int column, Pane box) {
        boxes[row][column] = box;
    }
    private void setOwner(int row, int column, Owner owner) {
        owners[row][column] = owner;
    }
} //}}}
class Owner extends Circle { //{{{
    private OwnerType type = OwnerType.NONE;
    private Owner() {} // Force all objects to use my provided constructor.
    public Owner(int size, OwnerType type) {
        super();

        int center = size / 2;
        setType(type);
        setCenterX(center);
        setCenterY(center);
        setRadius(center-5);
    }
    public OwnerType getType() { return type; }
    public void setType(OwnerType type) {
        this.type = type;
        setFill(type.getColor());
    }
} //}}}
class TitleLabel extends Label { // {{{
    final int padding = 30;
    private TitleLabel() {}
    public TitleLabel(int fontSize, boolean bold) {
        setFont(new Font(30));
        setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        setPadding(new Insets(30,0,30,0));

        if (bold) setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");
    }
} //}}}
enum OwnerType { // {{{
    NONE,
    WHITE,
    BLACK;

    public Color getColor() {
        switch (this) {
            case WHITE: return Color.WHITE;
            case BLACK: return Color.BLACK;
            default: return null;
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        switch (this) {
            case WHITE: return "White";
            case BLACK: return "Black";
            default: return "None";
        }
    }
}; //}}}
```